# Overwriting a property's accessors

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'll just jump right in.

Suppose AudioFile is an abstract class like so:

```cs
abstract class AudioFile 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in most cases, using a.Title is perfectly suited for other classes that inherit from AudioFile. However, in the case of MPEG files, this is stored in a different object in the id3 variable:

```cs
class MPEG : AudioFile 
{
    private ID3 id3;

    public new string Title {
        get {
            return id3.Title; 
        }
        set {
            id3.Title = value;
        }
    }
}

class WMA : AudioFile
{

}
```

What I would like is to do the following:

```cs
AudioFile a;

if( isMPEG ) {
    a = LoadMPEG(); // Returns a new MPEG instance.
} else
if( isWMA ) {
    a = LoadWMA();  // Return a new WMA instance.
}

Console.WriteLine( a.Title );
// Other stuff with a.
```

I would expect the output to be, whether an MPEG or a WMA, the song's title. However, when its MPEG, it doesn't work as expected (because it isn't using the id3 object). The only way it works is:

```cs
if( isMPEG ) {
    MPEG a = LoadMPEG();    // Returns a new MPEG instance.
    Console.WriteLine( a.Title );
    // Other stuff with a.
} else
if( isWMA ) {
    WMA a = LoadWMA();  // Return a new WMA instance.
    Console.WriteLine( a.Title );
    // Other stuff with a.
}
```

Which is not what I want. And ideas on how to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the abstract class property `virtual` so that derived classes can override it if they need different behaviors.

```
abstract class AudioFile
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; } 
}

class MpegFile : AudioFile
{
    public override string Title { /* your custom getter and setter */ }
}

AudioFile file = new MpegFile();
string title = file.Title; // will use override
```

In your version, you leave the abstract class property non-virtual and mark the derived class property as `new`. This allows you to use your custom behavior *only* via the reference of the derived class. You lose the ability to experience the polymorphic behavior via the base. The `new` modifier hides the base behavior *only* through the derived reference. Base references use the base behavior.

```
AudioFile file = new MPEG(); // will use base behavior for non-virtual methods
MPEG file = new MPEG(); // will use derived behavior when non-virtual methods are hidden by new
```

---

You may happen to come from a Java background. In C#, members are not virtual by default. You must mark them as `virtual`, and use `override` to replace or augment the base implementations in a polymorphic way. (For abstract members in abstract classes, you would use the keyword `abstract` instead of `virtual`.) The `new` keyword is useful when the base method is not virtual, but you have already seen its limitation.

Comment: Great answer, worked like a charm. Thanks! And yes, I do come from a Java background. :)